# Interpreting dummy variables created in caret train

Tags: r, r-caret

I understand from reading various answers [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/120546/rpart-using-caret-changes-names-of-factors),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22200923/different-results-with-formula-and-non-formula-for-caret-training),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36421296/caret-and-dummy-variables), that the `train` function from `caret` will create dummy variables to deal with factors that have multiple levels.

Here is an example using `mtcars` (model is useless other than to show point):

```
library(caret)
library(rattle)

df <- mtcars

df$cyl <- factor(df$cyl)
df$mpg_bound <- ifelse(df$mpg > 20, "good", "bad")

tc <- trainControl(classProbs = TRUE, summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)

mod <- as.formula(mpg_bound ~ cyl)

set.seed(666)

m1 <- train(mod, data = df, 
            method = "rpart", 
            preProcess = c("center", "scale"),
            trControl = tc)

fancyRpartPlot(m1$finalModel)

m1$finalModel

n= 32 

node), split, n, loss, yval, (yprob)
      * denotes terminal node

1) root 32 14 bad (0.5625000 0.4375000)  
  2) cyl8>=0.124004 14  0 bad (1.0000000 0.0000000) *
  3) cyl8< 0.124004 18  4 good (0.2222222 0.7777778) *
```

I don't understand this part `cyl8>=0.124004`. I get that `cyl8` is the dummy variable for the factor but what does it mean that `cyl8>=0.124004`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to extend the existing answer, because I don't think the conclusion reached in the comments is true. As you say, when using the formula interface, caret's train function will transform factor variables into dummy variables that only take the values 0 or 1, e.g. cyl8 == 1 means 'the car has 8 cylinders'.  Each dummy variable makes a statement about a characteristic that is either true or false for the observation.
Rpart will nevertheless output a numeric value as the split criterion, so that cyl8 >= 0.5, cyl8 >= 0.2 and cyl8 == 1 all mean the same thing "This car has exactly 8 cylinders". By default, rpart will choose the split value cyl8 >= 0.5 for binary dummies to indicate that the dummy is true. The interpretation of `cyl8 >= 0.5` is then "Does the car have 8 cylinders?" (and *not* "Does the car have more than 8 cylinders?")

```
df <- mtcars

df$cyl <- factor(df$cyl)
df$mpg_bound <- ifelse(df$mpg > 20, "good", "bad")

library(caret)
tc <- trainControl(classProbs = TRUE, summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)
set.seed(166)
m1 <- train(mod, data = df, 
        method = "rpart", 
        #preProcess = c("center", "scale"),
        trControl = tc,
        metric = "ROC")

m1$finalModel
   #1) root 32 14 bad (0.5625000 0.4375000)  
     #2) cyl8>=0.5 14  0 bad (1.0000000 0.0000000) *
     #3) cyl8< 0.5 18  4 good (0.2222222 0.7777778) *
```

The confusing value in your example is caused because caret apparently applies the preProcessing to the extended dataset where the dummies are numeric variables. The interpretation stays the same, but the (arbitrary) split value is transformed.

```
# Transform to dummies
mm <- model.matrix(mpg_bound ~ .-1, data = df)

# Do pre-processing
pp <- preProcess(mm, method = c("center", "scale"))
mm.pp <- as.matrix(predict(pp, mm))

# Dummy-Split in the middle
(max(mm.pp[,"cyl8"]) + min(mm.pp[,"cyl8"]) ) / 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this value represents the split point based on the dummy var scale (0-1). This code produces the same outcome:

```
df = mtcars

df$cyl <- factor(df$cyl)
df$mpg_bound <- ifelse(df$mpg > 20, "good", "bad")

tc <- trainControl(classProbs = TRUE, summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)

data = cbind(df,model.matrix(~cyl+mpg_bound,df)) # binds the dummy transf to the data

mod <- as.formula(mpg_bound ~ cyl8)

m1 <- train(mod, data = data, 
        method = "rpart", 
        preProcess = c("center", "scale"),
        trControl = tc)


m1$finalModel
```

It might be easier running the rpart code directly (incl original scale), although this might not allow you to specify the features you used. e.g.

```
 rpart(mpg_bound~cyl,data=df,method="class")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I'm still a tad confused. What exactly do you mean by the split point? Can this be interpreted practically with regards to my factor? Maybe I will take your advice are just run separately in rpart.

Comment: The split point is the point that maximally distinguishes class categories in a tree-like structure. So for the non-dummy variables if the best split in terms of df$cyl is around 8, for example the best guess is to say that cars with 8 cyl and higher are predominantly good (or bad) according to the data. In the dummy case this is transformed to a value between 0-1. I'm not exactly sure how this leads to the displayed value though. If you run `table(df$cyl,df$mpg_bound)` you can see where the split is made

Comment: Ok I think I'm starting to understand. Just to absolutely clarify: I can interpret this statement `cyl8>=0.124004` as "does have 8 cylinders or more" and this `cyl8< 0.124004 18` as "has less than 8 cylinders"?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not fully sure how the dummy score relates to the cyl values so I would only interpret the rpart code output (I will look into this). Mind that the non-dummy output (rpart) actually splits at 4 cylinders so that 4 or lower equals 100% good while 6 cylinders or more equals 21 bad, including 3 misclassifications (cyl6 = good).

Comment: but yes, if you look at the table values of the nodes this implies that `cyl8>=0.124004` splits the output at 8 cylinders or more (vs less than 8)

Comment: Ok great. I will check with my real data using the non-dummy variables that `>` always corresponds to including the factor using caret.